# Coldfusion Changing changing application variables with cfcache

Tags: coldfusion

I have been having this issue lately with changing application variables. I set application variables on application start and and then have a file that calls ApplicationStop() for when I want to restart the application. This works fine on a dev environment.

The problem I'm having is on the live environment. I clear the cfcache and hit the applicationStop file. This works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't. Also, we have 2 live servers which are load-balanced, so I have to go through this procedure twice and sometimes it works on one but not the other.

EDIT:

Sorry I wasn't clear enough. The problem is that the values for the application variables are not changing when I change them on the application.cfc file.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "This works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't". Also, you're not really asking a question here. You need to state your problem clearly: what you expect, how your expectations aren't being met; what the relevant code is; how you've tried to solve the issue, etc. Suggested reading: http://blog.adamcameron.me/2012/12/need-help-know-how-to-ask-for-it.html, http://blog.adamcameron.me/2013/09/short-self-contained-correct-compilable.html

Comment: @AdamCameron thank you. I see that my question wasn't clear enough. I have added a, clearer statement of the problem.

Comment: What about *every other point* I raised in my comment and the articles I linked to? Did you even read then? Voting to close as this is a waste of everyone's time.